# Populate Picker with List values Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, picker

I am trying to populate Picker with data from List that contains SQLite data.

I am doing it the same way I was doing in normal UWP project.
However I get path to my Model class instead of Model value requested.

```
        List<Rango> DB_RangoList = new List<Rango>();
        DatabaseHelper db_helper = new DatabaseHelper();
        DB_RangoList = db_helper.GetAllRangoData();
        if(DB_RangoList != null)
        {
            foreach (var RangoNo in DB_RangoList)
            {
                RangoPicker.Items.Add(RangoNo.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And my db_helper looks like this:

```
    public List<Rango> GetAllRangoData()
    {
        return (from data in sqliteconnection.Table<Rango>()
                select data).ToList();
    }
```

Model is like this:

```
[Table("Rango")]
public class Rango
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RangoNo { get; set; }
}
```

What is wrong in my approach?

Comment: Try using `RangoPicker.Items.Add(RangoNo.ColumnName.ToString());`

Comment: RangoNo is Column Name.

Comment: Then the scope of your `RangoNo` var in the `foreach` would suggest that the code would read `RangoPicker.Items.Add(RangoNo.RangoNo.ToString());`

Comment: yes, you are right. It was refering to the record not the value of the record. So RangoNo.RangoNo.ToString() works perfectly. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: No problem. Scoping can be confusing. I recommend renaming the `var RangoNo` in the foreach to something like `var record`.

Comment: yees. good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of your `RangoNo` var in the `foreach` would suggest that the code would read `RangoPicker.Items.Add(RangoNo.RangoNo.ToString());`